# jQuery JSON parse unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I basically read some sensor data and this data gets written to a JSON file. I'm trying to show these readings on a web page but I have as good as no previous experience with jQuery.
My measurements.json file contains exactly the same as the commented output var. However when i use the commented line it works. But it does not work when i run the code like here;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $("#json").load('measurements.json');

    //var output = jQuery.parseJSON('{"timestamp": 1391524099.334835, "pH": 1.4132352941176471, "Temperature": -14.934640522815688, "Chlorine": 999.0},');

    var output = jQuery.parseJSON("#json");

    $('#celc').append(String(output.Temperature));
    $('#cl').append(output.Chlorine);
    $('#ph').append(output.pH);

});
</script>

<div id="json"><strong>JSON</strong>: </div>
<div id="celc"><strong>Temperatuur</strong>: </div>
<div id="cl"><strong>Chloor</strong>: </div>
<div id="ph"><strong>Zuur</strong>: </div>
```

Im probably doing something obvious wrong but i cant seem to figure it out using just Google.

Thanks!

Comment: what is , in last of json that is comented

Comment: You're probably trying to parse the json before the data was actually loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [**$.getJSON()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

```
$.getJSON( 'measurements.json' function(data){
    $('#celc').append(String(data.Temperature));
    $('#cl').append(data.Chlorine);
    $('#ph').append(data.pH);
}).error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

[**.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is called asynchronously. Thus when you call `jQuery.parseJSON("#json");` it contains `<strong>JSON</strong>:` which is invalid JSON thus you are getting exception

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. I'm not getting any errors any more! What I don't understand is that my <div id>'s now don't get append. Or maybe it does but its just empty text. Is there a way to check or solve this?